# How i can Convert an array in PHP to Use AnyChart

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create some graphs stuff,but i'm having some problems to convert an array Key => Value to X = Key,Value=>Value.

AnyChart needs this:
x: "A", value: 637166

and i Have this:
x => Value

I Trying something like that:

```
$dadosproc=array();
$a=0;
foreach($dados as $key => $value){
    array_push($dadosproc,$dadosproc[$a]["x"]= $key,$dadosproc[$a++]["value"]=$value);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you might want an output array maybe similar to,

```
$dadosproc = array();
$a = 0;
$dados = ["x1" => 637166, "x2" => 637168];
foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
    $dadosproc[$a]["key"] = $key;
    $dadosproc[$a]["value"] = $value;
    $a++;
}

var_dump($dadosproc);
```

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(2) "x1"
    ["value"]=>
    int(637166)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(2) "x2"
    ["value"]=>
    int(637168)
  }
}
```